# unit testing .net core 2.2 SignalR hub issue with HubContext

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, xunit, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub that I wish to unit test. The hub is pretty straightforward except that it includes an IHubContext parameter in the ctor. The issue I'm having is that any attempt to unit test the UpdateData method such that I can verify the DataModel data property gets updated fails on a null reference exception. So far all I can verify is that the method get called.
Is it the case that I have not mocked the HubContext dependency properly?

Can anyone provide details of how to resolve this problem please?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Moq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Job { get; set; }

    }

    public class DataHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<DataHub> _hubContext;

        private DataModel data;

        public DataHub(IHubContext<DataHub> context)
        {
            _hubContext = context;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "DataGroup");
        }

        public void UpdateData(DataModel update)
        {
            data = update;
            _hubContext.Clients.Group("DataGroup").SendAsync("Data", data);
        }

    }

    public class DataHubTests
    {

        private DataModel update;
        private DataHub hub;

        Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
        Mock<IHubClients> mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
        Mock<IHubContext<DataHub>> mockHubContext = new Mock<IHubContext<DataHub>>();
        Mock<IGroupManager> mockGroups = new Mock<IGroupManager>();

        public DataHubTests()
        {
            SetupData();

            mockClients.Setup(clients => clients.All).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);

            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);
            mockGroups.Object.AddToGroupAsync("1234", "DataGroup", cancellationToken);

            mockHubContext.Setup(x => x.Clients.All).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);            
            mockHubContext.Setup(groups => groups.Groups).Returns(mockGroups.Object);

            hub = new DataHub(mockHubContext.Object);


        }

        private void SetupData()
        {
            update = new DataModel();
            update.Name = "Bob";
            update.Job = "Builder";
        }

        [Fact]
        public void DataHubIsAThing()
        {
            Assert.NotNull(hub);
        }

        [Fact]        
        public void UpdateDataIsCalled()
        {
            // act
            hub.UpdateData(update);
            // assert
            mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.All, Times.Once);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. There are simple errors like missing semicolons as well as entire classes/interfaces that are missing. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help answer your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, the code sample can now be compiled and run.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue. The IHubContext is injected in the .ctor of my Hub class in order to access the Clients list for sending messages, but when unit testing you have to mock the IHubContext for SignalR to work in the test.

My Hub Service .ctor

```cs
public MyHubService(IHubContext<MyHubService> context, MyDbContext db)
{
    _context = context;
    _db = db;
}
```

My Hub Service Method

```cs
public async Task SendNotification(string message)
{
    await _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notification", message);
}
```

My Unit Test

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task SendNotification()
{
    Mock<IHubClients> mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
    Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
    mockClients.Setup(clients => clients.All).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);

    var hubContext = new Mock<IHubContext<MyHubService>>();
    hubContext.Setup(x => x.Clients).Returns(() => mockClients.Object);

    var db = MyDBMock.GetMock();
    MyHubService hub = new MyHubService(hubContext.Object, db);

    await hub.SendNotification("Yo! This is the unit test.");

    mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.All, Times.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core v3.0, with some custom group enter/leave methods, I used the following:

```cs
public class MyHubTests
{
    private MyHub myHub;
    private Mock<IHubCallerClients> mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerClients>();
    private Mock<IGroupManager> mockGroups = new Mock<IGroupManager>();
    private Mock<IClientProxy> mockClientProxy = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
    private Mock<HubCallerContext> mockContext = new Mock<HubCallerContext>();
    private List<string> groupIds = new List<string>()
    {// *** NOTE: Technically these are not deterministic ***
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    };

    private List<string> clientIds = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2" };

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        mockClients.Setup(client => client.All).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);
        mockClients.Setup(client => client.OthersInGroup(It.IsIn<string>(groupIds))).Returns(mockClientProxy.Object);
        mockGroups.Setup(group => group.AddToGroupAsync(It.IsIn<string>(clientIds), It.IsIn<string>(groupIds), new System.Threading.CancellationToken())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
        mockGroups.Setup(group => group.RemoveFromGroupAsync(It.IsIn<string>(clientIds), It.IsIn<string>(groupIds), new System.Threading.CancellationToken())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
        mockContext.Setup(context => context.ConnectionId).Returns(It.IsIn<string>(clientIds));

        myHub = new MyHub()
        {
            Clients = mockClients.Object,
            Groups = mockGroups.Object,
            Context = mockContext.Object
        };
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GroupOpenedOrClosedInvalidArgumentsThrows()
    {
        myHub.Invoking(async h => await myHub.OpenedGroup(null, "Alice"))
            .Should().Throw<HubException>();

        myHub.Invoking(async h => await myHub.ClosedGroup(null, "Alice"))
            .Should().Throw<HubException>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AllClientsNotified()
    {
        await myHub.SendMessage("TEST", "TEST MESSAGE");

        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.All, Times.Once);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GroupNotifiedWhenGroupOpened()
    {
        var id = groupIds[0];

        await myHub.OpenedGroup(id, "Alice");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(id), Times.Once);

        await myHub.OpenedGroup(id, "Bob");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(id), Times.Exactly(2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GroupNotifiedWhenGroupClosed()
    {
        var id = groupIds[0];

        await myHub.ClosedGroup(id, "Alice");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(id), Times.Once);

        await myHub.ClosedGroup(id, "Bob");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(id), Times.Exactly(2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task EnsureGroupsAreSeparate()
    {
        var alpha = groupIds[0];
        var bravo = groupIds[1];

        await myHub.OpenedGroup(alpha, "Alice");
        await myHub.OpenedGroup(alpha, "Bob");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(alpha), Times.Exactly(2));

        await myHub.OpenedGroup(bravo, "Charlie");
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(alpha), Times.Exactly(2));
        mockClients.Verify(clients => clients.OthersInGroup(bravo), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

A simplified version of my Hub class:

```cs
public async Task OpenedGroup(string groupId, string user)
{
    try
    {
        Guid group = Guid.Parse(groupId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "{function} {message}", this.GetType().Name, "Invalid Group call");
        throw new HubException("Invalid Group call");
    }

    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);
    await Clients.OthersInGroup(groupId).SendAsync("UserEnter", user);
}

public async Task ClosedGroup(string groupId, string user)
{
    try
    {
        Guid group = Guid.Parse(groupId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HubException("Invalid Group call");
    }

    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);
    await Clients.OthersInGroup(groupId).SendAsync("UserLeave", user);
}

//This is from the .NET Core SignalR documentation
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```